# KnockoutJS property doesn't update when changing value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a serie of checkboxes and I want to gather the selected one. The checkboxes are in div's and when the div is clicked the checkbox should get checked as well:

```
var oCheckBox = $($(this).find('.chkSocialMediaItem').get(0));
oCheckBox.attr('checked', !$(oCheckBox).attr('checked'));
```

This works just fine but KnockoutJS doesn't pick up the change and so doesn't update my counter on the selected items.

I read somewhere you need to trigger the change event. But when I listen to the change event on the checkbox it does actually get triggered.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks !

**Update:**

I have found a 'knockout' solution. 
In my div I did a data-bind off the 'click' and changed the checked value in that function:

```
<script type="text/html" id="Template">
    <div class="item" data-bind="click: DivClicked">
       <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsASelectedItem" class="chkSocialMediaItem"/>
    </div>
</script>


function SocialMediaSearchItem() {          
            this.IsASelectedItem = ko.observable();
            this.DivClicked = function () {
                this.IsASelectedItem(!this.IsASelectedItem());
            };
}
```

Is this the only solution? I would really like 2 see a Jquery solution as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `checked` binding only listens to the `click` event.  Manually triggering the click event ends up getting the box out-of-sync based on when the actual checked value is set.

The preferred way to set the value is to update your view model value, as you have done in your second example above.

However, if you are using [1.3beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/), then there is an easy way to connect an element with its corresponding data using the `ko.dataFor` API.  It would look something like:

```
  var oCheckBox = $('.chkSocialMediaItem'),
      data = ko.dataFor(oCheckBox[0]);
      data.selectedItem(!data.selectedItem());
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ! I'll check the beta monday when I'm back @ work :)

Comment: Oh that is handy, any idea how to find out what `property` a control is bound to as well as the viewModel?

Comment: There is not a way currently to do that, other than maybe parsing the `data-bind` attribute yourself and then using the property name with the data ( `data['somePropertyName']` )

Comment: Thanks a lot - would be useful to expose that functionality (or really just the ability to get the observable itself). That would make it a lot easier to write cross-cutting site-wide utilities

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, there is a way that you could get what you are after.  You can have Knockout's binding provider parse the element's bindings with the appropriate context and then work with the resulting object.  Would be like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BvYQd/.  More information about binding providers here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same issue... Although I did find a solution that worked for me that differed from the one posted by @RP Niemeyer, so I figured I would post it.

Knockout Version: 1.2.1 -- (knockout-1.2.1.js)

To uncheck the checkbox bound by Knockout I used the following

```
$('YourCheckBoxHere').removeAttr('checked');
$('YourCheckBoxHere').triggerHandler('click');
```

to check the checkbox bound by Knockout I used the following

```
$('YourCheckBoxHere').attr('checked', 'true');
$('YourCheckBoxHere').triggerHandler('click');
```

Hopefully if the other solution didnt work, perhaps this will =) ... wasted about 3 hours on this issue.