# Knockout.Js doesn't detect programmatically changed checkbox state

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a simple checkbox which has its value adjusted by a bit of infrastructure that I'm writing to persist state in localStorage. I am aware that this would normally be done by setting the viewModel but ***the infrastructure is unaware of any knockout bindings and has no access to them.***

I didn't think this would be a problem as I assumed that knockout was running off the 'change' event, however `$checkbox.prop('checked', true).trigger('checked')` fails to trigger my observable. Even using the click event directly doesn't get me quite what I need.

What events does knockout wire to? How do I get it to read the state of the control?

[jsbin showing this weird behavior here](http://jsbin.com/ocuyav/1/edit). Try selecting the checkbox directly versus clicking the button.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate - but that DID have enough clues to get me straightened out

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate at all. "The infrastructure is unaware of any knockout bindings and has no access to them" is a perfectly reasonable scenario with multiple widgets on one page and none of the answers for either question directly address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this turned out to be related to a jquery bug. I took to the github knockout issue tracker to track this down; [see here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/987).

Ultimately I ended up doing this in my component:

```
var isjQueryOld = /^(0|1)\.[0-8]\./.test($.fn.jquery); // <=1.8.*
var toggleCheckbox = isjQueryOld ? jQueryOldToggleCheckbox : function($el) { $el.trigger('click') } //https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/987


function jQueryOldToggleCheckbox($el) {
    //This should be simple right? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8595601/5056
    //and "simulating events to adjust knockout models" jasmine spec
    //all this is nessessary to get everything working with knockout
    var changeTo = !$el.prop('checked');
    if(changeTo)
        $el.attr('checked', true);
    else
        $el.removeAttr('checked');
    $el.trigger('click');
    $el.prop('checked', changeTo);
}
```

and in my code

```
        toggleCheckbox($el);
```

Comment: This causes Safari to hang

Comment: Hmm, I tried to recreate that issue i had but seems fine now. I did however change it to prop instead of attr.

Comment: I actually don't think prop will work (again, this is for older versions of jquery), `prop('checked')` does more than just setting the attribute

Answer (score 2):

I found a better way of doing that. Just put this code inside of your domready event:

```
    $("input:checkbox").bind('change', function () {
        $(this).triggerHandler('click');
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would work cross browser and across knockout and jquery versions. At the very least you would want to use the live form of the event binding.

Answer (score 1):

Knockout bindings don't really work in the way you are thinking.

Check out: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Here is one solution you can use, no jQuery, no custom binding.

Your html will stay the same.

```
var m = {
  isChecked: ko.observable(false),
  infrastructureUpdatesCheckbox: function() {
    this.isChecked( this.isChecked() === true ? false : true);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(m);
```

Comment: The question is about an infrastructure component that explicitly does not have access to the viewModel.  Your solution works in the paired down scenario because you access the viewModel. That's why I named the method `infrastructureUpdatesCheckbox` because it's infrastructure, not domain logic. I just need to simulate whatever event knockout actually observes.

Answer (score 1):

you should change checkbox' checked status via your view model:

```
 var m = {
   isChecked: ko.observable(false)
  //,infrastructureUpdatesCheckbox: function() {
    //$chk = $(':checkbox');
    //$chk
    //  .prop('checked', !$chk.prop('checked'))
    //  .trigger('change');
    //this.isChecked(!this.isChecked());  // this - is your view model
 }
};
```

here is updated version:

```
function InfrastructureUpdatesCheckbox(){

  var $cb = $(':checkbox');
  var cb = $cb[0];
  cb.checked = !cb.checked;  // manually change checked status
  $cb.triggerHandler('click');  // run all event handlers bound to 'click' event
}
```

I guess the issue is related to checkboxes (radio buttons) only. Other controls should behaive correctly when you trigger events manually.

Comment: Same suggestion as Jack's one

Comment: This requires access to the viewModel - what I am using is a bit of cross-cutting infrastructure so, as I said, it has no access to the viewModel - only to the controls themselves. The hting is that knockout has to work off of SOME event - if it's not 'change' then it's some other one. I need to know which event.

Comment: Knockout observes the events that input elements can trigger: checkbox - click event, input[type=text] - blur, etc. No magic there!

Comment: Right, so in the jsbin I gave try changing it to trigger click instead of change - it certainly reacts but in completely the wrong fashion. The observable is false when the box is checked and true when it is not!

Comment: When you trigger event manually all events handlers run before 'element.checked' status is set to a new value. So you need to change checkbox' state first (element.checked = !element.checked), and then run handlers (without triggering full event) via $element.triggerHandler('click')

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already found a solution to your problem but this might help someone else.

I have had the exact same problem. What I did was use a pub-sub pattern and have my component trigger its own change event. What you could then do is to have the instance of the infrastructure component that needs to update the model subscribe to that event and then update your model. Better still your model can subscribe to the event, that way your model knows about the infrastructure component rather than the other way around

That way your infrastructure component does not need to know about ko and you can re-use it anywhere else. I am sure it's only a matter of time before you find other uses for it if you plan to re-use that component.

Hope this helps (sorry there is no code as I can't post clients code on SO, but if anyone wants an example just say so and I'll do a jsfiddle to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this question! I actually did end up getting a solution. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20499415/5056

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what event knockout is listening for, you could probably wade into the source itself and figure it out, but one solution would be to use a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). In the `init` for the custom binding you can set whatever handlers you want for whatever events you want to capture (such as `changed`) and use that to force you binding to run `update`.

Comment: That's a fair suggestion - my big problem with it is that I've currently implemented this infrastructure as a jq ui widget, meaning that it will work on knockout or non-knockout controls. Changing it to work off custom binders means that I not only have to have two versions of the control, but two versions of each "stateSerializer" - one that works off of jquery, and one that works off viewModels. I would much rather simulate the events knockout watches from the onset.

Answer (score 0):

I've spend hours today falling into on-click loop with checked & click approach, trying ko.observable, pureComputed write or even infrastructureUpdatesCheckbox without success too long to explain to anybody who pay for my work why I'm not able to check the radio button in the damn Knockout. Unfortunately my context (Magento 2 checkout with purchased plugins) didn't allow me to implement valid view model so finally I've managed to solve the issue with simple hack to add second input type="radio" and show it on click:

```
selectRadioPayment: function (obj, event, method) {
        this.selectPaymentMethod(obj, event, method);
        $('.ko-payment-selector').show();
        $('#p_method_' + method).hide();
        $('#p_method_' + method).closest('.radio-payment-selector').show();
    },

    renderedPaymentMethods: function() {
        if(quote.paymentMethod) {
            var selectedMethod = quote.paymentMethod().method;
            $('#p_method_' + selectedMethod).hide();
            $('#p_method_' + selectedMethod).closest('.radio-payment-selector').show();
        }
    },

    <input class="radio-payment-selector" type="radio" class="hidden" checked />
    <input class="ko-payment-selector" type="radio" name="payment[method]" class="radio" event: {change: function(data, event){$parent.selectRadioPayment(data, event, $data.method)}}"/>
```

I hope it would help someone someday.