# Checked state not getting populated in viewmodel when set programatically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jqgrid

I believe this question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143366/knockout-js-doesnt-detect-programmatically-changed-checkbox-state) but as far as could see in the rules, if there is no answer and it is not the same scenario, I'm allowed to ask.

I've simplified my real scenario with the following, basically, the checkbox is getting checked through some **unaccessible code** which doesn't get the view model of knockout.js to detect. Is there a work around?

HMTL:

```
<input id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myValue" />

<div data-bind="text: myValue"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    myValue: ko.observable(false)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#myCheckbox").attr("checked", "checked");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: As of jQ 1.7, `.prop()` is the recommended method for checking boolean properties of an element.

Comment: I appreciate that but that was really a quick example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: What is meant by unaccessible? Please elaborate.

Comment: in my particular scenario, its jqGrid which manages the state of that checkbox

Comment: I'd say you'd have better results making this a jqGrid-specific question.

Comment: How is it that the checkbox has a `checked` binding if it's managed by jqGrid?

Comment: If jqGrid is managing the state of that checkbox, then jqGrid should be managing the state of that checkbox, not Knockout.  If you're trying to read the value out of that checkbox then look for an API on the jqGrid to retrieve it.

Comment: This is getting too off topic. this is not a jqgrid issue, this is an issue on any existing code which checks a checkbox programatically and the fact that knockout only tracks click event and not change event. In an ideal world we would use one tool for every job and there would be no interoperability issues but as it so happens, that's surreal and you need to work with what you have.

Comment: @Michael Best You can add data bindings programatically and only then applybindings which works fine.

Comment: @Rivers, since Michael Best actually maintains the Knockout codebase, it may be worthwhile to consider his advice.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Ryan Rahlf I did not know he maintains the knockout codebase and I have much respect towards him as with anyone who gives so much to the community. Doesn't mean however that "moving" this subject to a jqGrid will answer my question. I've given a simple javascript example to describe my problem and a simple search will show many have the same issue. jqGrid is one of many widgets, together with lots of existing infrastructure code that programatically changes checked state. I know how to work with jqGrid and get the data I need but would love if I could start working more and more with knockout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a checkbox is modified using the `setAttribute` function or the `checked` property, as jqGrid does, it doesn't trigger the `click` event that Knockout's `checked` binding uses; neither does it trigger a `change` event. To be able to detect these changes, you have different options depending on the browser/version: [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), [`DOMAttrModified`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php), and/or [`onpropertychange`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljufknus.php).

But I'd suggest avoiding those solutions and using what [jqGrid gives you](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents): either the `jqGridSelectRow` event or the `onSelectRow` callback. You might want to check out the [Knockout-jqGridBinding](https://github.com/CraigCav/Knockout-jqGridBinding) plugin that should give you a good starting point. It includes a `selectedItems` option that lets you bind an observable array to jqGrid's selected items (using the `onSelectRow` callback internally).

EDIT:
To re-iterate, I suggest you don't try to solve the problem by watching the checkboxes. But if that's the way you want to go, there's a jQuery plugin, [attrchange](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/) that provides cross-browser support for this.

Resources:

1. Knockout-jqGridBinding: https://github.com/CraigCav/Knockout-jqGridBinding
2. attrchange: http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/

Comment: Thanks Michael. The reason I was keeping this javascript only is because jqGrid is just one of many other widgets I have and other infrastructure core which frequently programatically changes the checked attribute (form builder and other cases). Ideally I would want to make one change instead of in all instances of where this happens, including modifying open source widgets (always an option). Should I investigate in extending the default checked binding or is it something that has been done like that for a reason (browser compatibility maybe)?

Comment: I can understand that it can be inconvenient to have a new binding for each widget you use, but I think it's almost always the better approach. In this case, the callbacks from jqGrid give you everything you need without worrying about watching for property changes.

Comment: I added info about *attrchange*, but I just did some testing and found that its results vary widely by browser. In Chrome and IE10, it only catches changes using `attr` (not using `prop`). In IE8, it catches all changes (even user clicking).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to which you linked explained that Knockout needs to be alerted of the change through a usual event, such as "click". Here is the idea posted there by Rustam:

```
function update(){
  var $cb = $(':checkbox');
  var cb = $cb[0];
  // change value directly on element
  cb.checked = !cb.checked;
  // propagate changes to KO
  $cb.triggerHandler('click');
}
setTimeout(update, 1000);
```

Of course the method more native to KO would be to change the observable on the model, like so:

```
var update = function() {
    viewModel.myValue(!viewModel.myValue)
};
```

Comment: None of his answers applied due to similar scenario as I described in my question, the code that changes the checked state, is unaccessible. I'll make it bold to emphasise that.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fix this on my code in which Foundation was taking control of the checkbox.  I ended up binding a click event which then checked on the checkbox to see if it was checked (we only had 1 checkbox that we were trying to keep track of).  I then updated the observable from that click event based on whether it was checked or not.

No way around this that I know of.

Comment: I see your point. I believe the best way would be to write a custom binding which would take care of the change event instead of only the click event. That way we could bind to any checkbox without any issues. I will be reading about those and post any feedback I may have.

Comment: Trying creating one too, the problem was for some reason (I wasn't about to go through a crap load of javascript and figure out why), the change event (which the update event knockout binds to) is not being triggered correctly.  So even building a custom bindingHandler was not able to work for us.  Its worth a shot and they are easy make, worse that happens is you lose 30 minutes.

Comment: I really want this functionality as knockoutjs will be a huge improvement to my codebase so I will invest some time in trying to figure out how this could work. I assume there was a very good reason they are not "supporting" the change event but using click instead but if it possible this means I can use it in many scenarios whether its a widget or infrastructure code.

Comment: Yup its an unfortunate thing, we just went around using checkboxes when possible and the one time we did we wrote our own code for handling it like I said above.  It sucks for sure.