# Knockout check binding doesn`t change model value by jquery "change" event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I`ve found this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767635/knockoutjs-property-doesnt-update-when-changing-value-with-jquery) anwser, but it no good for me.

I would like to have an ability to change model value without trigger "click" event. So right now when user change value (not in the fiddle) some code generate "change" event. But model doesn`t change it value.

So I have a

Model

```
    function AppViewModel() {
    //Common
    this.TimeType = ko.observable(0);
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
     viewModel = new AppViewModel();    
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#testId")[0]);

    $("#change").click(function () {
         $("#third").attr('checked', 'checked');
         $("#third").change();
         alert(viewModel.TimeType());
    });   
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="testId" class="holder main-holder">
        <div class="holder">
           <input checked="checked" data-bind="checked: TimeType" id="Time" name="Type" type="radio" value="0"><label for="Time" class=" ">First</label>
        </div>
        <div class="holder">
            </div><input data-bind="checked: TimeType" id="TimeWithTypeDay" name="Type" type="radio" value="1"><label for="TimeWithTypeDay">Second</label>
        </div>
        <div class="holder">
            <input id="third" data-bind="checked: TimeType" id="TimeWithDaysOfWeek" name="Type" type="radio" value="2"><label for="TimeWithDaysOfWeek" >Third</label>
        </div>
    </div>
            <input id="change" type="button" value ="Change"/>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/skiff/4Wnmu/3/

Comment: Can you please elaborate `I would like to have ability to change model value without trigger "click" event.` ?

Comment: I have a js ui framework, which handle clicks and trigger Change event. I can`t change it. So I need to have an ability to see what user change in viewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In knockout checked binding with radio button, the property should equal to the value of the radio button. And the value is always string. Check this working fiddle:

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Wnmu/10/).

*JS*

```
var vm = new AppViewModel();

$("#change").click(function () {
    vm.TimeType("2");
    alert(vm.TimeType());
});   

function AppViewModel() {
    this.TimeType = ko.observable("1");
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: It should be solution for all view models. So somewhere in the code triggered "change". And I can`t add viewModel to this code. I can only see, what change fired.

Answer (score 0):

[That](http://jsfiddle.net/damienobringer/4Wnmu/7/) is what you are looking for ?

```
viewModel.TimeType.subscribe();
```